# Watson Assistant - Error Occurred when Loading orgs from region selected

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I'm getting an Error 'occured when loading orgs from the selected region' when I go into Watson Assistant on IBM Cloud as shown below.

[image: Image showing error which displays]

I have tried to submit a support ticket but it wont let me as the submitting a ticket page just displays a spinner.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an org and space in your account. Watson Assistant still uses Cloud Foundry, and it appears in the United Kingdom region, you do not have an org or space.

To add an org or space, visit your account page and click **Add an organization**:

[image: screenshot of cf org]

You may already have an org or space in another region, so you can try switching regions first, to see if an org/space already exists for you in another region.

Comment: Let me know if you still have issues, or if you think there is another problem and I can assist you.